What's the fastest way to list all files in an S3 bucket with 1 million files into a TXT file?
list all files in an S3 bucket with 1 million files into a TXT file
I tried using s3cmd ls s3://bucket01/, but it's extremely slow and even unresponsive. Even if it succeeds, the speed is extremely slow, and listing 1 million files could take a month.

Either turn on and use the report from Amazon S3 Inventory, or setup and use a S3 Metadata Index

AWS CLI version 2 supports multithreading. The parameter max_concurrent_requests has a default value of 10, but you can increase this value to speed up the list operations, provided that your CPU can handle the increased load. The speed improvement is indeed significant!
